# Can’t open Built-In Apps in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I can’t open all my Windows Apps on Windows 10. When I try, the app is shown for about 1 second. The eventlog tells me that:

> Activation of app Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews failed
>   with error: The service cannot be started, either because it is
>   disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it. See
>   the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional
>   information.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the apps [with this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/) but the problem stays the same. Any ideas?

Comment: >See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information. -> Have you seen the log?

Comment: Where can I find this?

Comment: Ok the Log tells me this: 

Activation of the app Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it..

Comment: Take a look: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/the-service-cannot-be-started-either-because-it-is/58bf868f-6611-47b4-9d8f-f514d4302ff2

Answer (score 2):

Go to Services. Set the Windows Update service to "Manual" & Click on Start. It will start the service and your built-in apps should open fine now.